# DAX: How to reference a column in calculatetable to add another column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

---Edit as some progress made with original one ---

I'd need to look for value (cost) based on condition of 2 columns created in CALCULATETABLE, which those columns are summarized by Day and type of group.

I could come up to create a table as below which returns correct result.

```
CALCULATETABLE (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( Fact_daily, Dim_Calendar[DateKey], Dim_ServiceGroup[Group] ),
        "Total Weight", Measure_TotalWeight[Total Weight], "Vehicle Type", IF(Measure_TotalWeight[Total Weight] >= 100, "TRUCK", "BIKE") )
    ),
)
```

I need add another column (Cost) by referring the columns within, Dim_ServiceGroup[Group] and "Vehicle Type" here.  This COST is available in another table which list Group, Vehicle Type and Cost.

Once this table is created with the 'Cost' column, I will need to add this 'cost' to other cost in the Fact_daily table. ([base_charge] column)

I'm not even sure if my approach is appropriate or should need to look for other solution, but appreciate if anyone could help on this.

- I've created a separate table by adding a calculated column to the table to determine cost at first. Yet when I attempt to sumup with [base_charge], it only returned total value of all row and not by grouped.

Assuming this as I cannot create a relation between this table and Fact_daily table and start wondering if I complete the table without adding those calculated column...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need the table for other calculations or just to display it in a visual? from what I see so far you could have achieved same result in a visual with 2 measures instead of a table. What's the end goal that you're aiming for?

Comment: @Stachu, thanks.  I do not need the table but the result of the 'Cost' determined based on service group and vehicle type.  This new 'cost' to be added to other 'base cost' in different table by referring the group as a Final cost to be displayed in several visuals.    Would you mind advice what 2 measures could be used?